# else statement printing multiple time?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

i want to edit mobile number in given file address.txt but when i entered wrong mobile number this code print "Mobile number not found" multiple time if i have three entry in address.txt file then it will print three time "Mobile number not found". I want print one time my else statement help?

```
def editContact():
        obj2 = open("address.txt","r")  
        output = []
        number = raw_input("Enter 1 for edit email id and Enter 2 for edit phone number : ")
        if(number=="1"):
                old_number=raw_input("Enter old phone number  : ")
                for line in obj2.readlines():
                    if old_number in line: 
                           print line             
                           new_number=raw_input("Enter new phone number : ")
                           obj2 = open("address.txt","r")
                           aa=obj2.read()
                           s = re.sub(old_number, new_number, aa)    
                           obj1 = open("address.txt","w")
                           obj1.writelines(s)
                           print "Number Edit sucessfully"
                    else:
                           print "Mobile number not found"  
        else:
                 print "Incorrect choice"
```

**output :**

```
Mobile number not found
Mobile number not found
Mobile number not found
```

**desired output:**

```
 Mobile number not found
```

Comment: That is not valid Python code. You can't have an `elif` without a corresponding `if`. Post a [mcve].

Comment: Simply add a `break` statement after the `print "Mobile number not found"`

Comment: Download the excellent and free [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) Community Edition and learn how to set breakpoints and step through your code as it executes. If you do that, you won't need to ask questions like this any more

Comment: after break statement if part is not running only else working now @sciroccorics

Comment: @sciroccorics, in that case if the number is present in any line except for the first line the output will always be `Mobile number not found` because if number is not present in the first line then the else block will fire and cause exit from the for loop

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding : Your file has 3 entries(3 phone numbers), and if the input entry is not found, you want to print it only once.

```
import re

def editContact():
    obj2 = open("address.txt", "r")
    output = []
    number = raw_input("Enter 1 for edit email id and Enter 2 for edit phone number : ")
    if (number == "1"):

        old_number = raw_input("Enter old phone number  : ")

        for line in obj2.readlines():
            if old_number in line:
                print line
                new_number = raw_input("Enter new phone number : ")
                obj2 = open("address.txt", "r")
                aa = obj2.read()
                s = re.sub(old_number, new_number, aa)
                obj1 = open("address.txt", "w")
                obj1.writelines(s)
                print "Number Edit sucessfully"
                break

        else:
            print "EOF Reached, number not found!"
    else:
        print "Incorrect choice"

editContact()
```

The output is :
    `Enter 1 for edit email id and Enter 2 for edit phone number : 1
    Enter old phone number  : 123
    EOF Reached, number not found!`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a boolean variable for this. In this case `present` is the boolean variable introduced at the 6th line of the function.

```
def editContact():
        obj2 = open("address.txt","r")  
        output = []
        number = raw_input("Enter 1 for edit email id and Enter 2 for edit phone number : ")
        if(number=="1"):
                old_number=raw_input("Enter old phone number  : ")
                present = False # this will check if number is present or not
                for line in obj2.readlines():
                    if old_number in line: 
                           present = True # since number is present make it True
                           print line             
                           new_number=raw_input("Enter new phone number : ")
                           obj2 = open("address.txt","r")
                           aa=obj2.read()
                           s = re.sub(old_number, new_number, aa)    
                           obj1 = open("address.txt","w")
                           obj1.writelines(s)
                           print "Number Edit sucessfully"

                #After every line in text file is parsed check its value  
                if present == False:
                   print "Mobile number not found"  
        else:
                 print "Incorrect choice"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def editContact():
        obj2 = open("address.txt","r")  
        output = []
        number = raw_input("Enter 1 for edit email id and Enter 2 for edit phone number : ")
        if(number=="1"):
            old_number=raw_input("Enter old phone number  : ")
            for line in obj2.readlines():
                if old_number in line: 
                    print line             
                    new_number=raw_input("Enter new phone number : ")
                    obj2 = open("address.txt","r")
                    aa=obj2.read()
                    s = re.sub(old_number, new_number, aa)    
                    obj1 = open("address.txt","w")
                    obj1.writelines(s)
                    print "Number Edit sucessfully"
                    break
            else:
                print "Mobile number not found"  
        else:
            print "Incorrect choice"
```

Moving the `else` statement out of the loop shall solve the problem.
Also, a `break` inside the `if` statement will be necessary, else it will also repeat itself.